# Apache mod_proxy dynamic filter

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy

How can I configure Apache to ProxyBlock content based on something dynamic such as time-of-day or max-use.  Basicly I'm curious about the scriptability of Apache.  My web-stumbling leads me to believe I can combine mod-proxy and mod-perl in interesting ways to do dynamic filtering.  But I'm pretty lost.  What are some general instructions, tutorials, books, technologies to begin scripting Apache (or any suitable proxy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) is often used for this sort of thing, since it has a language for specifying ACLs that includes support for time of day, as well as a variety of other attributes.

However, if you were wedded to Apache (and I would really recommend **Squid** for something like this) you could do this with **mod_rewrite**, a programming `RewriteMap`, and whatever scripting language you prefer.  Use **mod_rewrite** to create a proxying `RewriteRule` that uses your script for generating the URL replacement, and then your script can implement whatever logic you want.